# How do I know if something is an eventEmitter in node?

Tags: node.js

The request object is also an Event Emitter, because i can put request.on(event, function), but how would I know that without seeing others do it?

Comment: Mostly, you go to the documentation.  But, you could also query it with code `console.log(request instanceof EventEmitter)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if object is instance of EventEmitter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36232312/check-if-object-is-instance-of-eventemitter)